# What are the differences between Ash and Red?

Tags: pokemon

In Pokémon, we have two main characters:

- Red, who is the main protagonist on the manga and the first Pokémon games (Red, Blue and Yellow)
- Ash, who is the main protagonist on the anime.

What are the differences between the two?

Comment: Good Q, never thought about it :)

Comment: Red (in the game) is mute. He never talks.... ever.

Comment: In Blue version, his name is [Blue](http://youtu.be/-2gVD79criY?t=2m12s).  Your rival is named Red.

Comment: @David I'm not speaking about the games. I'm speaking about the anime / manga.

Comment: Your question says "and the first Pokémon games", but since you can make any name you want it makes sense to standardize somehow.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I wrote the question almost a year ago. My bad. :-)

Comment: Ash CAN'T get rid of team rocket. They've fallen down GIANT pits, gotten to the bottom of the sea, and have fallen from they're balloon, like, a MILLION times, without dying! They are INVINCIBLE!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are **lots**!

[image]

For starters, Red is character who just starred in manga/games, and manga created only after a TV series aired.

As a result, they decided to release two types of manga, one based on the show and one based on the games:

- The manga based on games R/B/G/Y, called Pokémon Adventures, which continues the story until the third generation stages.
- And manga based on the series, called Pokémon The Electric Of Pikachu!

Comment: That image looks like more for fun than about serious differences, apart from one or two facts in it. :P

Comment: B.T.W I prefer the Japanese version just because it is not censored.
For example: real death appears much more realistic, And bigger b***s. :X
http://i.imgur.com/erK2T.png
http://i.imgur.com/8xkDh.png
http://i.imgur.com/oTn5e.png
Zombies!

Comment: The image is mostly right, but referring to the first pokemon-movie, Ash had way more than 10 Pokémon :D.

Comment: Didn't Ash catch like a bunch of Taurus lol. Btw thanks for this comment! I never knew about any manga based on the TV series. Going to read it right now!

Comment: @HashiramaSenju In the English scanlations Koga's arbok survived though. He regenerated himself and was just fine after that.